# Unable to retrieve members of a google group, getting Invalid Input

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-groups, google-groups-api

I created a Google group from the Google Groups homepage and have added 5 users.

I am trying to use the [Google Admin SDK API to retrieve the list of members from my group](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list) but whenever I try the API (from the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list#try-it)) I get a 400 :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Input"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Input"
 }
}
```

The request is :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/my-group-name%40googlegroups.com/members?key={MY_API_KEY}
```

My `groupKey` is urlencoded `my-group-name@googlegroups.com`

I tried using only `my-group-name` as the `groupKey` but I then get a `404 "Resource Not Found: groupKey"`

I am logged in with the owner of the group and have all scopes required during the OAuth2 authentication.

Answer (score 3):

The Admin SDK groups API calls [require](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites) Google Apps for Work or EDU. They do not work with consumer @googlegroups.com groups. There is no API to manage consumer googlegroups.com groups programatically.

Comment: I created the group from my work email though (jdoe@mycompanyname.com) which is a Google Apps for Work

Comment: Nevermind, it seems it wasn't activated for my company so it defaulted to a `@googlegroups.com`