# Is there still "no API to manage consumer googlegroups.com groups programatically"?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apis-explorer, google-groups-api

In an answer to this 2014 post
[Unable to retrieve members of a google group, getting Invalid Input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36037894/8879659)
you read: "There is no API to manage consumer googlegroups.com groups programatically".
Is this still the situation in 2018?

I tried to follow the suggestion in answer 3 of the post [How to get the list of members in a Google group in Google app script (Admin SDK)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784889/how-to-get-the-list-of-members-in-a-google-group-in-google-app-script-admin-sdk) but I get the following error message:

> ReferenceError: "AdminDirectory" is not defined. (line 9, file "Code")

where line 9 (and following)  is (are):

> ```
>     page = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupKey,
>     {
>         domainName: 'googlegroups.@com',
>         maxResults: 500,
>         pageToken: pageToken,
>     });
> ```

Searching to understand the error I found the reference page for [Members: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list). Using the "Try this API" form in that page I get the error reported in the first post I mentioned.

If it is NOT true that "There is no API to manage consumer googlegroups.com groups programatically", is there a guide to copy the list of the members of a group I own in a google-sheet sheet? (I mean to copy via a function, non by hand exporting and reimporting the CSV)
Many thanks, Roberto Scotti

Answer (score 0):

It's 2021 and I still can't find any evidence there's an API for @googlegroups.com groups, sadly.

Comment: This is arguably an acceptable answer, but would be better with information on what sources you'd checked to confirm this.