# Can you use Google API for non G Suite groups management?

Tags: api, google-api, google-workspace, google-groups, google-groups-api

I have a nonprofit that I'm working for who can't afford G Suite at the time, and I've successfully created email distribution lists for them to use via @googlegroups.com, but what I wanted was a way to manage that group via the Google API, but it appears that I keep getting a `"Resource Not Found: groupKey"` or `"Domain not found"`.

My question is whether I'm expecting too much to be able to administer free google groups via the API.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same use case. I don't think @googlegroups.com supports API access. From the [prereqs page](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites)

> The API supports G Suite, Education, and Government editions.

which implies there's no support for the free @googlegroups.com groups.

This SO answer also says the same thing https://stackoverflow.com/a/36037894/553994